# Is there a way to change the file type of bulk files distributed across bulk directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, rename, bulk

I am attempting to run a program that looks through a group of folders, and finds a type of file inside them. The format of the files is this

MAIN

> SUBDIR01
>
> > FILE01.TXT
> >
> > FILE02.TXT
>
> SUBDIR02
>
> > FILE03.TXT
> >
> > FILE04.TXT

The problem is that there are many files and many directories that the program runs through. And, as it was written, the program searches for .txt files. Being case-sensitive it finds none. The simple workaround I had was to re-write the program to search for .TXT and problem solved. I also have found that "rename" and "mv" can be used to rename files in bulk if I am located in the directory in which they are contained. But, have not found a way for me to be in the MAIN directory and have the bulk change go through a group of folders.

The closest thing I've found is find . -name "*.TXT" will print all of them out.

I feel like I'm pretty close, so I was wondering if anyone might off-hand know of a solution to this issue. Not using the above work around. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `find MAIN -type d -print` will give you a list of directories.  Loop on that list, `cd` to the directory, then use your `mv` command on the files of that directory.  Then `cd ..` to go back to MAIN.  Loop on the next one.  Without code, you will get general responses like that.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: @Jacob Please include the desired output. What should be the file names after renaming?

Comment: I don't see why this was down voted, seems like a legit question. Also, I think I was pretty clear that the issue is that the files are labeled .TXT and need to be labeled .txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find` to locate the files and print the names and then use `xargs` in combination with `rename` to do the actual renaming. To avoid problems with file and directory names containing spaces you should use `-print0` instead of `-print` with find and add `-0' to the`xargs` command line. See the example below.

```
find . -name '*.TXT' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/.TXT/.other/'
```